# how to interpret stack memory from gdb

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, stack

Fairly new to assemly, Having trouble understanding how to interpret stack memory when using gdb. I  understand that what bt and info frame shows. x/10x shows the first 10 values starting at the current stack pointer but how do you interpret it? the first column is the stack level, im assuming this means stack frame? and there are 32 bits after the first column, what do each of those hex value mean?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  zzz () at zzz.c:96
#1  0xf7d39cba in yyy (arg=arg@entry=0x0) at yyy.c:542
#2  0xf7d3a4f6 in yyyinit () at yyy.c:590
#3  0x0804ac0c in gnninit () at gnn.c:374
#4  main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd5e4) at gnn.c:389

(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffeac770:
eip = 0x8049047 in main (goo.c:291); saved eip 0xf7f1fea1
source language c.
Arglist at 0xffeac768, args: argc=1, argv=0xffffd5e4
Locals at 0xffeac768, Previous frame's sp is 0xffeac770
Saved registers:
ebx at 0xffeac75c, ebp at 0xffeac768, esi at 0xffeac760, edi at 0xffeac764, 
eip at 0xffeac76c

(gdb) x/10x $sp
0xffeac63c: 0xf7d39cba  0xf7d3c0d8  0xf7d3c21b  0x00000001
0xffeac64c: 0xf78d133f  0xffeac6f4  0xf7a14450  0xffeac678
0xffeac65c: 0x00000000  0xf7d3790e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(gdb) x/10x $sp
0xffeac63c: 0xf7d39cba  0xf7d3c0d8  0xf7d3c21b  0x00000001
0xffeac64c: 0xf78d133f  0xffeac6f4  0xf7a14450  0xffeac678
0xffeac65c: 0x00000000  0xf7d3790e
```

First column is memory address of the first byte following.

The other four columns are four 32 bit values stored in memory.

I.e. the first line means that at address 0xffeac63c the memory contains byte value 0xba, at address 0xffeac63d there is value 0x9c, etc.. up till address 0xffeac64b where the value 0x00 is stored (Intel is little endian, so dword `0xf7d39cba` is stored in memory as bytes `ba 9c d3 f7`).

What those values means .. well, `0xf7d39cba` is `0xf7d39cba`, a 32 bit value. Content of memory doesn't mean anything, until you give those values some meaning by the code which is using them.

I.e. if next instruction to execute is `ret` and `esp` is pointing at `0xf7d39cba`, then that value is used as return address.

If next instruction is `pop eax`, then that value will be fetched into register `eax`, and used for whatever the code does further with value in `eax`...

Comment: I found something similar to `print *(void **) $esp @ 10` to be useful for having gdb annotate pointers on the stack with symbolic names, while writing [Different Ubuntu versions binary execution differences](//stackoverflow.com/a/49763983).

Comment: did you get 0xba from the word 0xf7d39cba?

Comment: @cloudiebro yes, 0xf7d39cba is stored in memory as four bytes `ba 9c d3 f7` (in this order from least significant byte to most significant byte, because Intel is "little-endian" machine).

Comment: And memory is addressable by single bytes, i.e. each byte value (8 bits) stored in computer memory has it's own address (physical memory address), which is often virtualized and translated by OS into process address space, but either way in 32 bit mode the memory address (virtual or physical) is 32 bit value, so your way of printing stack content in 32 bit values is often more handy than single byte dump. But in hexadecimal formatting you can easily read the separate bytes (each hexa digit is exactly 4 bits => two digits are single byte).

Comment: im a little confused on 0xba being a byte, and i think you have a typo in your answer, did you mean  0xffeac63c when you said  0xffeac63d?

Comment: 0xba means integer value `BA` in hexadecimal ( `186` in decimal). And that fits into 8 bits (8 bits when interpreted as unsigned integer encoded in binary way covers range of values from 0 to 255, or 0x00 to 0xFF). The value `0xf7d39cba` is 32 bit value, as I wrote before, each hexadecimal digit is exactly 4 bits "wide" (because there are 16 digits 0 to F, and 4 bits can have 16 different states from 0000 to 1111, so F7 is one byte (8 bits) - the most significant one, D3 is second byte, 9C is third byte and BA is fourth byte (least significant one). No typo. Memory is addressable by bytes.

Comment: @cloudiebro i.e. after memory address `0xffeac63c` the next byte is at address `0xffeac63d` ... the gdb shows you only the address of the first byte on each line, and it shows 16 bytes per line (four 32 bit values = 4x4 = 16 bytes), so every address shown is +16 to previous one. But the separate single bytes still exist in the memory, at all the addresses between. Computer memory in x86 machines is addressable by single bytes (+1 address).  (8 bits = 1 byte, 32 bits = 4 bytes)